# Lable line points with geographical coordinates in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, labeling

I have a .shp file set of Congressional districts as lines.  Since the lines are composed of geographic coordinates, is it possible to label a point on a line and have the label automatically show the coordinates?

Answer (score 3):

You have to make two virtual fields (x,y)
[image]
In style manager write this expression
[image]
[image]

Comment: You can use the same expression directly in the labelling tab. For projections in meters, it might be usefull to use `to_int($x)` or `round($x,1)` to cut off or shorten sub-meter digits. If you don't have a point layer, you can use `Extract nodes`from the Vector Geometry tools menu.